# After code-splitting, build files aren't deployed to heroku

Tags: heroku, uglifyjs

I recently applied code-splitting and I'm using CRA(create-react-app).

After that, I deployed my build files to heroku but I got this error message.

```
 error An unexpected error occurred: 
 "/tmp/build_bfd38a5e7aeec15ffefbe9481e36ace7/node_modules/uglifyjs-
 webpack-plugin: EROFS: read-only file system, access '/usr/local/bin'".
```

I think this is mainly because my bundle.js is split into 4 separate chunks which change bundle file hugely.

For further information, here is my asyncComponent.js and App.js.

```
// asyncComponent.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default function asyncComponent (getComponent) {
    return class AsyncComponent extends Component {
        static Component = null;
        state = {
            Component: AsyncComponent.Component
        };

        componentWillMount () {
            if (!this.state.Component) {
                getComponent().then(({ default: Component }) => {
                    AsyncComponent.Component = Component;
                    this.setState({ Component });
                });
            }
        }

        render () {
            const { Component } = this.state;

            return Component && <Component {...this.props} />
        }
    };
}

// App.js
import asyncComponent from './lib/asyncComponent';

const AsyncHome = asyncComponent(() => import('./pages/Home'));

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={ AsyncHome } />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.  It appears to be related to Yarn `v1.0.0`.  If you explicitly set your yarn engine to `0.28.4`, your builds should work again.  See this relevant GitHub issue: [heroku-buildpack-nodejs 468](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/468)

In your `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
    "yarn": "0.28.4"
}
```

Comment: I think this solution works for my case. Are there any other problems related to a higher version of yarn? Say v1.0.0.

Comment: Yes, the issue is related to Yarn `v1.0.0`.  For the time being, it's best to use `0.28.4`.  It appears that the Heroku team is working on a patch that will warn users in the build process.